# Cams stuck in Ikea case

Tags: wooden-furniture

[image]

When I turn on these cams to dismantle this Ikea case, the wood splits and there's no turning happening. What to do please?

Comment: It's cracking because you're leaning sideways on it.  You turn them 180 degrees to release them. Ikea furniture is not made to be disassembled, given the cost of it you may be better just going to Ikea and buying what you want.

Comment: I've already disassembled this cupboard once before so I know it can be done. But this time it's splitting the wood and didn't turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the index mark is aligned with the stud when the panels are assembled, and the cam is turned clockwise, it should pull the panels together. The photo shows an unusual gap, which may exceed the pull range of the cam. It also appears that the cam has been turned counter-clockwise based on the position of the index mark. Alternatively, the cam has been turned almost 360 degrees clockwise, which is excessive in this application.

The split in the bottom panel is an indication that the cam is applying leverage to the engaging stud, rather than connecting to the collar of the stud. If you are unable to force the panels closer together, consider to back a few turns out on the stud to allow the collar to engage the cam. This will pull them together more effectively.

Comment: But I want to disassemble this not assemble ! It's been assembled in my attic. I now need to remove it but it's too big to go through the hatch.

Answer (score 1):

You always undo these cams by turning counter-clockwise until the moulded arrow points toward the bolt. Usually this only requires approximately a quarter-turn.

It looks to me that your case was only loose-assembled in the attic. Whoever put it there didn't bother to align the cams, engage the bolts and tighten the cams. The gap suggests that the bolt is not engaged in the cam.

In your case, if all the other cam-bolts have a similar gap, you shouldn't need to turn the cam, the case should pull apart.

If you are disassembling these cases only in order to get them out of the attic for disposal, you could just take a hand-saw (or whatever type of power saw and long extension lead you own or can borrow) into the attic and cut it up in situ, avoiding cutting through the bolts etc. Or use a hacksaw (etc) to cut the bolts. Or use a large club-hammer and/or wrecking bar.

Comment: You were right. It wasn't even secured and just pulled apart !